# conditional grouping based on group invariant column value

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have a data frame:

```
temp = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,2,-3,1,1,2,3,-2,0,2,1,-5,1,1,2,1,3,0,0,3,2,4,-1,1,3,2,2,0,1,3,2,4,3,0), ncol=5,byrow = TRUE))
colnames(temp) = c("ID","srch","utility","reutility","code")
```

I need to group by "ID" column. For any "ID" value, "srch" column stays the same. For each group, if srch > 1 I need min(utility where code==1)-max(reutility where code ==0) else (i.e. if srch<=1) I need it to be 0.

This is the output I need:

```
temp = as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,4,2,0,3,-1), ncol=2,byrow = TRUE))
colnames(temp)=c("ID","Val")
```

Any code using dplyr is great but others are welcome too.

Comment: Hi Tecsanto.I think it is excellent that you provided a minimal executable example. Unfortunately it does not execute. You try to set  5 colnames on a data.frame with 4 columns...

Comment: Hi Dario, please excuse my error. Kindly check now (I modified ncol=5)

Comment: Shouldn't ID = 2 be 0?

Comment: But for ID = 2, `srch == 1`...and you say if it is 1, then you need it to be 0... *else (i.e. if srch<=1) I need it to be 0.*

Comment: Sorry sotos. You are correct. I got confused. It should be 0. Edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming output for `ID = 2` is 0, we can do :

```
library(dplyr)

temp %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Val = if(first(srch) > 1) min(utility[code == 1]) - 
                                      max(reutility[code == 0]) else 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     ID   Val
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4
#2     2     0
#3     3    -1
```